# Apache Flink "Could not materialize checkpoint"

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to enable RocksDB checkpointing for my use case and I keep getting the error below.

```
AsynchronousException{java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 1 for operator Map -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1).}
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointExceptionHandler.tryHandleCheckpointException(StreamTask.java:1153)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.handleExecutionException(StreamTask.java:947)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:884)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 1 for operator Map -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1).
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.handleExecutionException(StreamTask.java:942)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtils.java:394)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.<init>(OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:853)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerUtils.snapshotBackwardsCompatible(TypeSerializerUtils.java:49)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:546)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerUtils.snapshotBackwardsCompatible(TypeSerializerUtils.java:39)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.<init>(NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.<init>(CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.java:127)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction$StateSerializerSnapshot.<init>(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:851)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction$StateSerializer.snapshotConfiguration(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:785)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction$StateSerializer.snapshotConfiguration(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:613)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.RegisteredOperatorStateBackendMetaInfo.computeSnapshot(RegisteredOperatorStateBackendMetaInfo.java:170)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.RegisteredOperatorStateBackendMetaInfo.snapshot(RegisteredOperatorStateBackendMetaInfo.java:103)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendSnapshotStrategy$1.callInternal(DefaultOperatorStateBackendSnapshotStrategy.java:123)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendSnapshotStrategy$1.callInternal(DefaultOperatorStateBackendSnapshotStrategy.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.AsyncSnapshotCallable.call(AsyncSnapshotCallable.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtils.java:391)
    ... 7 more
```

The flink-config.yaml is

```
################################################################################
    #  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    #  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    #  distributed with this work for additional information
    #  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    #  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    #  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    #  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    #      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    #  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    #  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    #  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    #  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    # limitations under the License.
    ################################################################################


    #==============================================================================
    # Common
    #==============================================================================

    # The external address of the host on which the JobManager runs and can be
    # reached by the TaskManagers and any clients which want to connect. This setting
    # is only used in Standalone mode and may be overwritten on the JobManager side
    # by specifying the --host <hostname> parameter of the bin/jobmanager.sh executable.
    # In high availability mode, if you use the bin/start-cluster.sh script and setup
    # the conf/masters file, this will be taken care of automatically. Yarn/Mesos
    # automatically configure the host name based on the hostname of the node where the
    # JobManager runs.

    jobmanager.rpc.address: fl-service

    # The RPC port where the JobManager is reachable.

    jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123


    # The heap size for the JobManager JVM

    jobmanager.heap.size: 1024m


    # The heap size for the TaskManager JVM

    taskmanager.heap.size: 1024m


    # The number of task slots that each TaskManager offers. Each slot runs one parallel pipeline.

    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1

    # The parallelism used for programs that did not specify and other parallelism.

    parallelism.default: 1

    # The default file system scheme and authority.
    #
    # By default file paths without scheme are interpreted relative to the local
    # root file system 'file:///'. Use this to override the default and interpret
    # relative paths relative to a different file system,
    # for example 'hdfs://mynamenode:12345'
    #
    # fs.default-scheme

    #==============================================================================
    # High Availability
    #==============================================================================

    # The high-availability mode. Possible options are 'NONE' or 'zookeeper'.
    #
    high-availability: zookeeper

    # The path where metadata for master recovery is persisted. While ZooKeeper stores
    # the small ground truth for checkpoint and leader election, this location stores
    # the larger objects, like persisted dataflow graphs.
    #
    # Must be a durable file system that is accessible from all nodes
    # (like HDFS, S3, Ceph, nfs, ...)
    #
    high-availability.storageDir: file:///opt/flink/ha-storage

    # The list of ZooKeeper quorum peers that coordinate the high-availability
    # setup. This must be a list of the form:
    # "host1:clientPort,host2:clientPort,..." (default clientPort: 2181)
    #
    # Since K8s automatically load balances to an active node, using the service works fine
    high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: zk-service:2181


    # ACL options are based on https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_BuiltinACLSchemes
    # It can be either "creator" (ZOO_CREATE_ALL_ACL) or "open" (ZOO_OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE)
    # The default value is "open" and it can be changed to "creator" if ZK security is enabled
    #
    # high-availability.zookeeper.client.acl: open

    # Other options recomended by https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html#config-file-flink-confyaml
    high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /flink
    high-availability.cluster-id: /cluster_one
    high-availability.jobmanager.port: 50010

    #==============================================================================
    # Fault tolerance and checkpointing
    #==============================================================================

    # The backend that will be used to store operator state checkpoints if
    # checkpointing is enabled.
    #
    # Supported backends are 'jobmanager', 'filesystem', 'rocksdb', or the
    # <class-name-of-factory>.
    #
    state.backend: rocksdb

    # Directory for checkpoints filesystem, when using any of the default bundled
    # state backends.
    #
    state.checkpoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/checkpoints

    # Default target directory for savepoints, optional.
    #
    state.savepoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/savepoints

    # Flag to enable/disable incremental checkpoints for backends that
    # support incremental checkpoints (like the RocksDB state backend).
    #
    state.backend.incremental: true

    state.checkpoints.num-retained: 2

    #==============================================================================
    # Web Frontend
    #==============================================================================

    # The address under which the web-based runtime monitor listens.
    #
    #web.address: 0.0.0.0

    # The port under which the web-based runtime monitor listens.
    # A value of -1 deactivates the web server.

    rest.port: 8081

    # Flag to specify whether job submission is enabled from the web-based
    # runtime monitor. Uncomment to disable.

    #web.submit.enable: false

    web.upload.dir: /opt/flink/web-uploads

    #==============================================================================
    # Advanced
    #==============================================================================

    # Override the directories for temporary files. If not specified, the
    # system-specific Java temporary directory (java.io.tmpdir property) is taken.
    #
    # For framework setups on Yarn or Mesos, Flink will automatically pick up the
    # containers' temp directories without any need for configuration.
    #
    # Add a delimited list for multiple directories, using the system directory
    # delimiter (colon ':' on unix) or a comma, e.g.:
    #     /data1/tmp:/data2/tmp:/data3/tmp
    #
    # Note: Each directory entry is read from and written to by a different I/O
    # thread. You can include the same directory multiple times in order to create
    # multiple I/O threads against that directory. This is for example relevant for
    # high-throughput RAIDs.
    #
    # io.tmp.dirs: /tmp

    # Specify whether TaskManager's managed memory should be allocated when starting
    # up (true) or when memory is requested.
    #
    # We recommend to set this value to 'true' only in setups for pure batch
    # processing (DataSet API). Streaming setups currently do not use the TaskManager's
    # managed memory: The 'rocksdb' state backend uses RocksDB's own memory management,
    # while the 'memory' and 'filesystem' backends explicitly keep data as objects
    # to save on serialization cost.
    #
    # taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false

    # The classloading resolve order. Possible values are 'child-first' (Flink's default)
    # and 'parent-first' (Java's default).
    #
    # Child first classloading allows users to use different dependency/library
    # versions in their application than those in the classpath. Switching back
    # to 'parent-first' may help with debugging dependency issues.
    #
    # classloader.resolve-order: child-first

    # The amount of memory going to the network stack. These numbers usually need
    # no tuning. Adjusting them may be necessary in case of an "Insufficient number
    # of network buffers" error. The default min is 64MB, teh default max is 1GB.
    #
    # taskmanager.network.memory.fraction: 0.1
    # taskmanager.network.memory.min: 64mb
    # taskmanager.network.memory.max: 1gb

    #==============================================================================
    # Flink Cluster Security Configuration
    #==============================================================================

    # Kerberos authentication for various components - Hadoop, ZooKeeper, and connectors -
    # may be enabled in four steps:
    # 1. configure the local krb5.conf file
    # 2. provide Kerberos credentials (either a keytab or a ticket cache w/ kinit)
    # 3. make the credentials available to various JAAS login contexts
    # 4. configure the connector to use JAAS/SASL

    # The below configure how Kerberos credentials are provided. A keytab will be used instead of
    # a ticket cache if the keytab path and principal are set.

    # security.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache: true
    # security.kerberos.login.keytab: /path/to/kerberos/keytab
    # security.kerberos.login.principal: flink-user

    # The configuration below defines which JAAS login contexts

    # security.kerberos.login.contexts: Client,KafkaClient

    #==============================================================================
    # ZK Security Configuration
    #==============================================================================

    # Below configurations are applicable if ZK ensemble is configured for security

    # Override below configuration to provide custom ZK service name if configured
    # zookeeper.sasl.service-name: zookeeper

    # The configuration below must match one of the values set in "security.kerberos.login.contexts"
    # zookeeper.sasl.login-context-name: Client

    #==============================================================================
    # HistoryServer
    #==============================================================================

    # The HistoryServer is started and stopped via bin/historyserver.sh (start|stop)

    # Directory to upload completed jobs to. Add this directory to the list of
    # monitored directories of the HistoryServer as well (see below).
    #jobmanager.archive.fs.dir: hdfs:///completed-jobs/

    # The address under which the web-based HistoryServer listens.
    #historyserver.web.address: 0.0.0.0

    # The port under which the web-based HistoryServer listens.
    #historyserver.web.port: 8082

    # Comma separated list of directories to monitor for completed jobs.
    #historyserver.archive.fs.dir: hdfs:///completed-jobs/

    # Interval in milliseconds for refreshing the monitored directories.
    #historyserver.archive.fs.refresh-interval: 10000


    # Additional Settings
    metrics.internal.query-service.port: 50011

    # Other things that would be added by docker-entrypoint.sh
    # if I wasn't overwriting the file.
    blob.server.port: 6124
    query.server.port: 6125
```

The code can be fount at https://github.com/varnost/Corengine. The only change to make it work/crash if line #30 in `Corengine/src/main/java/io/varnost/base/LogStream.java`. If I comment that out it works fine, with it in, it crashes.

What am I doing wrong to get RocksDB to checkpoint successfully?

Thank you!

Comment: My suspicion is that you are using a `TypeSerializer` which does not support `#snapshotConfiguration`. Could you check which type serializer you are using when the `AbstractMethodError` is thrown?

Comment: @TillRohrmann, Do you have any references for that? I've been looking for something on the incompatibility and how to make the serializer work. I'm using the Jackson serializer on input, but the SimpleStringSerializer is throwing the error on output back to Kafja. https://github.com/varnost/Corengine/blob/e3e66aabaf109c37a381e6f0bdb015a89a7e036e/src/main/java/io/varnost/base/LogStream.java#L66

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the exact reason why this caused the issue. But I was compiling for v1.7.2 and running on 1.8.0. When I updated my pom.xml to build for flink v1.8.0 (so the versions matched) the error went away and checkpoints are completing successfully.

Comment: It seems that Flink `1.7.2` is not binary compatible with Flink `1.8.0`. Sorry for the inconveniences. Keeping binary compatibility is sometimes really hard. With `1.8.0` the community added support for state schema evolution which caused the incompatibility.